# Why does the recordsource-query of an continuous-form gets slow when a filter is attached?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

The recordsource of my continuous-form looks like this:

```
SELECT ONLINE_ANTRAG.*, ONLINE_ANTRAG_TYP.OAT_NAME, ol_infoVerknuepfung([ONLINE_ANTRAG].[LFD],[ONLINE_ANTRAG].[OA_KEY_OAT]) AS xInfoVerknuepfung
FROM ADUSER RIGHT JOIN (ONLINE_ANTRAG_TYP RIGHT JOIN ONLINE_ANTRAG ON ONLINE_ANTRAG_TYP.LFD = ONLINE_ANTRAG.OA_KEY_OAT) ON ADUSER.CN = ONLINE_ANTRAG.OA_BEARBEITER
ORDER BY ONLINE_ANTRAG.OA_EINGANGSZEIT;
```

ol_infoVerknuepfung is a big, complex function which does several DLookup's to the table ONLINE_ANTRAG_TYP. All the Tables are in a SQL Server which is connected via an odbc-Datasources.

When requerying the form without a filter the form rebuilds in about 500ms (which is totally ok). The ~ 40 calls to the function ol_infoVerknuepfung will last between 5 and 10 ms each.

So far so good.

But when I attach a filter to the form like this:

```
x_filt = "xInfoVerknuepfung Like '6*'"
Me.filter = x_filt
Me.FilterOn = True
```

it takes about 12 seconds to requery and every call to ol_infoVerknuepfung will last between 150 ms and 200 ms.

After some research I found out that the reason for the slowdown are several calls of DLookup (like this):

```
something = DLookup("OAT_VERKNUEPFUNG_WHERE", "ONLINE_ANTRAG_TYP", "LFD=52")
```

which were instantly executed before (<1ms) and after the setting of the filter each call will be between 15ms and 40ms each.

So why there is this big difference and what can I do against it?

**Edit:**

I tried to replace the calls to DLookup with this function:

```
Private Function ol_dSpecialLookup(ByVal expression As String, ByVal domain As String, ByVal criteria As String) As Variant

  With my_DB.OpenRecordset("select " & expression & " as result from " & domain & " where " & criteria)
    Call .MoveFirst
    If .RecordCount = 1 Then
      ol_dSpecialLookup = !Result
    Else
      ol_dSpecialLookup = Null
    End If
  End With

End Function
```

but this function takes 15 to 30ms without a filter and 45 to 65ms with the filter.

Comment: You need to read about, understand, and start using parameterized queries. This code is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: sql injection is no issue. Everything stays internally and the user which uses this has full access to the database anyway.

Comment: @Sean Lange: btw: If you know a way to use parameterized queries as a recordsource in a ms-Access VBA-form feel free to tell me how to do it. As far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: My guess is OL_info is being called over and over.  A work around is to replace the select query with a make table query to make a temporary table.  Set the record source of your form to the temporary table.  Then when the filter is set it is just a normal filter and should run almost instantly.  Delete the temporary table in the form close event.